# How to save result from calculation into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, calculator

I'm develop a BMI calculator application to save the bmi result as well as height, weight and date, time. Unfortunately, it only saved result for height and weight and the page wont calculate the bmi(when click on calculate button) and wont save the bmi result into database(it saved only height and weight and not the result). Please, really need help. Thank you for your time. [image: Interface]

```
databaseBMIs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BMIs");

    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    saveBMI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBMI);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);

    saveBMI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addBMI();
        }
    });
}

public void bmiCalculator(View v) {
    String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
    String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

    if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
            && weightStr != null && !"".equals(weightStr)) {
        float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr) / 100;
        float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);

        float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

    }
}

private void displayBMI(float bmi) {
    String bmiLabel = "";

    if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_severely_underweight);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 16f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.severely_underweight);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 16f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.underweight);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 25f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 25f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 30f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.overweight);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 30f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 35f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_i);
    } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 35f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 40f) <= 0) {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_ii);
    } else {
        bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_class_iii);
    }

    bmiLabel = bmi + "\n\n" + bmiLabel;
    result.setText(bmiLabel);

}

public void addBMI() {
    String height_bmi = height.getText().toString();
    String weight_bmi = weight.getText().toString();
    String result_bmi = result.getText().toString();
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    final String datetime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(height_bmi)) {

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your height", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(weight_bmi)) {

        String id = databaseBMIs.push().getKey();

        BMI Bmi = new BMI(id, height_bmi, weight_bmi, result_bmi, datetime);

        databaseBMIs.child(id).setValue(Bmi);

        Toast.makeText(this, "BMI added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your weight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Page3Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Height"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="6"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="top"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_below="@id/height"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Weight"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
                android:id="@+id/weight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="6"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="top"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_below="@id/weight"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Calculate"
                android:background="#df5d46"
                android:onClick="bmiCalculator"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveBMI"
                android:layout_below="@id/weight"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:background="#df5d46"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the displayBMI method ()
At the end of the addBMI method

For example

```
public void bmiCalculator(View v) {
String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
        && weightStr != null && !"".equals(weightStr)) {
    float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr) / 100;
    float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);

    float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

     displayBMI(bmi)//<<<<<Very important

    }
}
```

Successfully
Friend

Comment: appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you have shared *bmiCalculator()* is never called and is *displayBMI()*. These methods are necessary to display the result. The method *bmiCalculator()* should probably be called in **addBMI()** and then call *displayBMI()* with those results.

The code should look something like this:

```
var calculation = bmiCalculator();
displayBMI(calculation);
```